# Where is the main class of Kafka located?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, apache-kafka, java-8

I want to set up Kafka source code with IntelliJ IDEA and I am able to successfully build the project but the Run configurations are incorrect.

I have loaded and successfully build the Gradle project in IDEA. I looked around and found [a blog post](https://manasvigupta.github.io/getting-started-with-contributing-to-apache-kafka-part1-build-and-run-kafka-from-source-code/) that configures this but some of the run configurations he stated are just not possible. For eg, there is no class `kafka.Kafka` and the `-cp` flag is not `core_main` as stated in the module.

My setup is as following:
[image]

How do I setup the run configurations so that I can execute and debug Kafka's source code?

Answer (score 0):

The kafka.Kafka is [here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/5a4bbb9f91f583a9c27a2f64f28547033da4f4fb/core/src/main/scala/kafka/Kafka.scala). It is a scala class.

Install Scala plugin. Press double shift shortcut and go to Kafka.scala file. Click on the green triangle next to the `main` method. This will create a run configuration. You can then edit it to add any custom stuff.

[image]